# What is happening in this urlpatterns list of Python Django urls.py file?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, typeerror, django-urls

I have three versions of `urls.py` file.

Here are imports (shared between versions):

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from main import views
```

**Version 1.** Everything works fine here. No problems running `python2 manage.py runserver`.

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    url(r'^bio$', 'views.bio_view'),
)
```

**Version 2.** Hmm I need some more urls though. Let's add them. No problems here either.

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^bio$', 'views.bio_view'),
)
```

**Version 3.** Wait a sec... What is `''` doing here? I don't actually need it. Let's remove it, shall we?

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^bio$', 'views.bio_view'),
)
```

And here is the issue after running the `manage.py` server:

(Some of top `django` library calls ommitted)

```
  File "/home/konrad/workspace/mydir/myproject/urls.py", line 20, in <module>
    url(r'^', include('main.urls')),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py",     line 52, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in    import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/konrad/workspace/mydir/myproject/urls.py", line 15, in <module>
    url(r'^bio$', 'views.bio_view'),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 91, in patterns
    t.add_prefix(prefix)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 232, in add_prefix
    self._callback_str = prefix + '.' + self._callback_str
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'RegexURLPattern' and 'unicode'
```

So... Actually the question is about the **Version 2.** - why is it fixing the **Version 3.** error? And what is the error?

What is actually happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're surprised; you removed a parameter, and things went wrong. (Your first version might well have "worked" when you ran the server, but I doubt you could actually get to the URL.)

You are using an old version of Django. In this version, `urlpatterns` must be defined with the result of the `patterns` function. The first parameter to that function is a prefix to apply to all view strings. Your prefix is empty, but that doesn't mean you can just remove it; your first URL is now being taken as the prefix parameter.

In recent versions it was recognised that this prefix is confusing and rarely used. As a result, the `patterns` function is removed and there is no prefix; the value of `urlpatterns` must now be a simple list. Additionally, views in urls must be callables, not strings.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So in theory Version 1 should raise `TypeError` to prevent false positive - first `prefix` argument has to be a `string` object. Do you agree? I think this is the reason of the confusion here.

Comment: Possibly, yes. However since this syntax has now been completely removed from Django, there's nowhere to make that change.